# type field in analyzer definition

Tags: elasticsearch

If I define my index with this analyzer (C#):

```
settings = new
{
    index = new
    {
        number_of_shards = 1,
        number_of_replicas = 1,

        analysis = new
        {
             analyzer = new
             {
                 analyzer_standard_with_html_strip = new
                 {
                     type = "standard",
                     char_filter = new string[] { "html_strip" },
                     stopwords = "_english_"
                 },
```

What does the type field do? Does it base the analyzer on the standard analyzer? If I don't have the type line at all it seems to work. This, from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html, seems to suggest you don't need it:

> In this example, we configure the html_strip character filter to leave
>    tags in place:
>
> ```
> PUT my_index
> {
>   "settings": {
>     "analysis": {
>       "analyzer": {
>         "my_analyzer": {
>           "tokenizer": "keyword",
>           "char_filter": ["my_char_filter"]
>         }
>       },
>       "char_filter": {
>         "my_char_filter": {
>           "type": "html_strip",
>           "escaped_tags": ["b"]
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

There, the analyzer has no type specified. Shouldn't it be "custom"?

So, what does the type field do when you're defining an analyzer? What is the difference between

```
"my_analyzer": {
  "type": "standard",
  "tokenizer": "keyword",
  "char_filter": ["my_char_filter"]
}
```

and

```
"my_analyzer": {
  "type": "custom",
  "tokenizer": "keyword",
  "char_filter": ["my_char_filter"]
}
```

and

```
"my_analyzer": {
  "tokenizer": "keyword",
  "char_filter": ["my_char_filter"]
}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a custom analyzer, you are supposed to specify `"type": "custom"` or leave out the `type` setting but it's not a good practice and doesn't help convey the meaning of what you're doing.

You can also specify `"type": "standard"`, but only if you're only configuring a `standard` analyzer, like for instance here we're configuring an `english` analyzer, but it is not a custom one.

```
"my_english_analyzer": {
  "type": "standard",
  "max_token_length": 5,
  "stopwords": "_english_"
}
```

So your analyzer `analyzer_standard_with_html_strip` should be of type `custom`. If you want to reuse the `standard` analyzer in your `custom` analyzer but add a character filter, you can redefine the [`standard` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) as a custom one, i.e. use the same tokenizer and token filters + add the character filter, like this:

```
"analyzer_standard_with_html_strip": {
  "type": "custom",
  "tokenizer": "standard",                 <--- like standard
  "filter": [ "standard", "lowercase" ],   <--- like standard
  "char_filter": ["my_char_filter"]        <--- this is custom 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. It sounds more like a convention - and I'm quite happy to follow convention - rather than a necessity. i.e. nothing will break if I accidentally get it wrong?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "break" :-) Your input might not be analyzed like you expect, but other than that the risk is low.